# What is the default strategy for device placement in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to set up distributed training. Right now I have one parameter server and two workers. If I add another parameter server how will Tensorflow split up the parameters between the two servers? Is it done randomly or do I need to manually specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They get placed round-robin on available ps tasks, see [device_setter_test.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/27711108b5fce2e1692f9440631a183b3808fa01/tensorflow/python/training/device_setter_test.py)